# Google calendar API - search event by name

Tags: calendar, google-search-api, google-calendar-api

I use a query parameter q=something to search

From the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference?csw=1#Queries)  it is evident that q=**"Match entire phrase"** will return all events that match Match AND entire AND phrase

But I cannot search for an event something like this **"abc 1.34 - 3.03 p.m."** to be clear whenever there is a minus sign the search breaks understanding it as negation

I tried escaping minus as - by  **"abc 1.34 \- 3.03 p.m."** but I was not successful.

How do I search for the event by exact which has numbers and special chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing a deprecated documentation. Instead try [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). There is a [Try-it section](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it). I placed a query statement in the 'q' parameter and it worked, returned the event to me:

```
  {
     "kind": "calendar#events",
     "etag": "\"p328xp1nqajltc9g\"",
     "summary": "myname@gmail.com",
     "updated": "2017-10-12T14:25:18.442Z",
     "timeZone": "Underworld",
     "accessRole": "owner",
     "defaultReminders": [
      {
       "method": "popup",
       "minutes": 30
      }
     ],
     "nextSyncToken": "abcdefghijklmno",
     "items": []
    }
```