# Google Calendar Event

Tags: google-calendar-api

How to display google calendar event on google search page when any one search by location?

I have created google calendar event through google calendar event API using C#.It works perfect but I want to display that events in google page when any one search by location then it will be display like given image.

Any help about how can I do it?

[i want to display google calendar event like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXmDU.jpg)

Comment: Try using `q` parameter for `event.list`. If you include the location in the event then search it with the` q` parameter it will return all events that match Match AND entire AND phrase, see related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46713338/5995040) for additional information.

Comment: do you provide me any example how can i pass  with `q` parmater?

Comment: Hi Mr.Rebot,

Thanks for your answer.i got list when i pass search value in q parameter.
but my question is some thing other.
I want to display that all events in google search page when any one search in search box like below imag.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXmDU.jpg